CURL : (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect
I'm making a GET request to an endpoint. It returns the following error.
The URL is reachable from a browser, and the request is executing in a docker container behind corporate proxy.
Command:
curl -v <my_target_URl>

Error:
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to <my_target_URL>:443 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to <my_target_URL>:443

Why is this happening?
I tried bypassing the proxy but same error.
 curl -v https://<my_target_URL>
* Uses proxy env variable no_proxy == '127.xxxxx'
* Uses proxy env variable https_proxy == 'http://xxxxxxx'
*   Trying xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to nexus.xxxxx port xxxxx (#0)
* allocate connect buffer!
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to <my_target_URL>:443
> CONNECT <my_target_URL>:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: <my_target_URL>:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
< 
* Proxy replied 200 to CONNECT request
* CONNECT phase completed!
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* CONNECT phase completed!
* CONNECT phase completed!
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to <my_target_URL>:443 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to <my_target_URL>:443


Eh? Title of your post says you are using curl, but your first paragraph says you are using a browser. It might have been helpful if you'd shown the command line you actually executed. What do the proxy logs say? When you "bypassed the proxy" did this share DNS or routing inside the corporate network with the original method?

What does proxy logs show? How are you performing the request?

@symcbean i updated my post with command used

I hope that's not the command you used - it would have crashed and burned. There shouldn't be a space between the '-' and the 'v'. And it won't get routed via a proxy.

@symcbean, haha no no it's just a typo error while updating the post. I used the right command with no space obviously

So you didn't specify any proxy? You need to [edit] the question with all applicable information. We are not clairvoyant, contrary to popular belief.

I added my command verbose . This should give more details

openssl s_client -showcerts... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742003/how-to-debug-ssl-handshake-using-curl
